# Is there a way to show markup in the viewer outside of editMode?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm looking for a way to show markups when not in editMode. I want to be able to draw markups in the viewer while at the same time being able to use edit2D. Everytime I call `leaveEditMode()` on the markups extension, the markups disappear. If there was just a way to have them always showing even when not in edit mode, that would do the trick. I have seen stuff about a view mode but the enterViewMode() must be outdated as I cannot find it.

Another option would be to leave edit mode on in the markups extension and also use the edit2D tools simultaneously by changing which drawing layer/canvas is on top? I have no idea if that's possible or how to go about it though.

Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question so much as a "how do I use autodesk forge"? Did you ask wherever autodesk says community support can be found?

Comment: This is their main community support. Also, I am attempting uncommon behavior of the viewer's extensions (which is typically encouraged by them) and am asking what possibilities exist from someone who knows the inner-workings of their viewer (the forge team).

Comment: such a weird thing for an application to go "please ask on stackoverflow", but hey, if that's what they say, hopefully they actually look at their own tags.

Comment: I agree haha. But it's 100% what they do. They are pretty on top of answering though which is cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out a way, I'm not sure what the repurcussions would be, but it seems to work.
Here's an edited code snippet I threw together quick to test and it seems to work. Basically I do the opposite of what `enterEditMode()` and `leaveEditMode()` already do. Basically `markupsExtension.editModeSvgLayerNode` holds the svg data for all the markups. When `leaveEditMode()` is called, it clears out `markupsExtension.svg`. So I just add it back after it's called manually. I also clear it out before re-entering because it does it on it's own and it might interfere.

```
if (buttonName === 'markup') {
    let markupsExtension = this.viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');
    if (this.selectedButton === buttonName) {
        // Exit markups
        markupsExtension.leaveEditMode();

        // Shows the markup after leaving
        if (markupsExtension.editModeSvgLayerNode.svg) { 
            markupsExtension.svg.appendChild(markupsExtension.editModeSvgLayerNode.svg);
        }
    }
    else {
        this.selectedButton = buttonName;

        // Remove the svg set we added so it can redraw it in "enterEditMode()"
        if (markupsExtension.editModeSvgLayerNode && markupsExtension.editModeSvgLayerNode.svg.parentNode) {
            markupsExtension.svg.removeChild(markupsExtension.editModeSvgLayerNode.svg);
        }
        markupsExtension.enterEditMode();
    }
}
```